# Need to display the result in new activity

Tags: android, eclipse

The result of first activity is displayed in the same screen(window)(activity).I just need to display the result in another activity.Can someone please tell me how to do that.The main activity is as follows :

```
package com.example.knowyourself;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
Button submit;  
String temp;    
DatePicker dt;
int day, month, year, choice;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)      
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);          
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
    addListenerOnButton();  
}

public void addListenerOnButton()
{
    submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);       
    dt = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);   
    submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()     
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            day = dt.getDayOfMonth();   
            month = dt.getMonth();      
            year = dt.getYear();        
            choice = (day + month + year) % 5;
            switch (choice) 
            {
            ..............
                            ..............
            }
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You are" +           
                    temp,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);                                   
            t.show();                                                       
        }
});
}
}
```

Also the activity_main is a s follows :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/green"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
    android:text="@string/Date"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" 
    android:textColor="@color/blue"
    android:textScaleX="0.9"
     />

<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
    android:background="@color/lightblue"

    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/datePicker1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
    android:text="     "
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
    android:background="@drawable/one"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: By "next screen" you mean you want to start another activity that continues on from your main? 
Also, is the text within your `Toast` object your output?

Comment: yes..I want to display the result in second screen..i.e.next window..and yes..

Comment: what exactly are you asking? it's very unclear

Comment: The result of my program is displayed in the same page where i submit it.I need to know how could I show it in the next activity(screen)(window)....

Comment: @user3035473 Be specific what do you want to show in another activity ?

Comment: I just need to display the result in next activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

In MainActivity :

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(this, Other_Activity.class);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_ID", "SOME DATAS");
startActivity(intent);
```

In Other_Activity :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
String datas= extras.getString("EXTRA_ID");
if (datas!= null) {
    // do stuff
}        
}
```

Also check this : [Android Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

To start a new activity, you simply use [Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html). For example, if you want to start an activity that is stored in `NewActivity.java` from your current activity, use this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
i.startActivity();
```

However, if you want to parse data from one activity to another you need to use arguments. For example, if your ouptut is in the `temp` variable of your main activity, use this to pass it to the new activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
i.putExtra("output", temp);
i.startActivity();
```

Then from the `onCreate()` method of your new activity retrieve the String via:

```
String result = getIntent().getStringExtra("output");
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You are " + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to print result when submit button is clicked, do following steps.

- Create intent for intended activity

  ```
     Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OtherActivity.class);
  ```

  - Set result to that intent

intent.putExtra("key", value);

- Start new activity

  ```
  startActivity(intent);
  ```
- Get result in other activity

  ```
  int value = getIntent.getExtras.get("key");
   // not necessarily int, any value
  ```
- Display result in any `Textview`

  ```
   textView.setText(""+value);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a new layout , to the new layout screen you can make what you want .

Comment: Thats what i need to know how...since Iam a beginner in android...

Comment: You should put this on click action :   startActivity(new Intent(FROMTHISACTIVITI.this,TONEWACTIVITICLASS.class));

Comment: After you create TO_NEW_ACTIVITI_CLASS.class , in this class you should like this <code> protected void                             onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.MY_NEW_LAYOUT);
 }</code>

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking it is not clear but I think what you need is [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)