# Displaying the result in another activity

Tags: android

Asked this question before but didn't get it properly.Iam a beginner.So it's difficult to cope initially.The output to the program is displayed in the same activity.I just want to see the result displayed in the another activity. Below is the mainActivity.java

```
package com.example.knowyourself;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button submit;  
String temp,out;    
DatePicker dt;
int day, month, year, choice;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)      
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
    addListenerOnButton();  

}

public void addListenerOnButton()
{
    submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);        
    dt = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);   
    submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            day = dt.getDayOfMonth();   
            month = dt.getMonth();      
            year = dt.getYear();        
            choice = (day + month + year) % 5;
            switch (choice) 
            {
            ...........
                            ...........
            out="You are"+temp;
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,out, 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);                                    
            t.show();                                                       
        }
});
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/green"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
    android:text="@string/Date"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" 
    android:textColor="@color/blue"
    android:textScaleX="0.9"
     />

<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
    android:background="@color/lightblue"

    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/datePicker1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
    android:text=""
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
    android:background="@drawable/one"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you can use intents or sharedpreferences to share data through app, read about those

Comment: I think your problem is more about understanding what an activity is - this might mean you are trying to do things that are to hard for you (yet). The exact solution depends on whether you are in an activity calling to some other activity to fetch data, or you are in an activity that is trying to send the data back.

Comment: What is wrong with this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20323845/1112882 on your old question? Clarify things there instead of creating another question.

Answer (score 1):

please remove toast and do this in your file.

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);   
i.putExtra("STRING_DATE", out);
startActivity(i);
```

on the Second Activity, do like this in your onCreate() method,

```
Textv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
String output = getIntent().getExtras().getString("STRING_DATE");
Textv.setText(output);
```

The result would be displayed on the Second Activity;

Answer (score 0):

You can send `out` to another activity using an [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Something along the lines of:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AnotherActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("out",out);
startActivity(intent);
```

Another option is [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) but I feel like an `Intent` is better in this case.

Answer (score 0):

try to read [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html), this is good tutorial for beginner and you will get better understanding for passing data from current activity to another activity. This was the first tutorial for me also.

Answer (score 0):

Send data using intent like this.

`Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
 i.putExtra("yourdataName",yourdataValue);`

and get that data in SecondActivity using Bundle like this.

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras(); 
String strUrData=b.getString("yourdataName");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void addListenerOnButton()
 {
 submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);        
 dt = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);   
 submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
 {
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        day = dt.getDayOfMonth();   
        month = dt.getMonth();      
        year = dt.getYear();        
        choice = (day + month + year) % 5;
        switch (choice) 
        {
        ...........
                        ...........
        out="You are"+temp;
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AnotherActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("out",out);
       startActivity(intent);                                                     
    }
    });
   }
```

and in the second activity:

```
   public class AnotherActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)      
  {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);     
    Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();
    if(b!=null){
    String str=b.getString("out");

     Toast t = Toast.makeText(AnotherActivity.this,str, 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);                                    
        t.show(); 

    }

  }

  and don't forget to declare the Second Activity in the manifest file
```

Comment: it shows an error when i type "out" in toast.Rest everything is fine.

Comment: check now..the answer is edited

Comment: thanks bro..its working but everything in 1st layout(activity_main) is displayed in second activity while displaying result in second activity.

Comment: create another layout file for the second activity..and set that layout...through setContentView() method, if your new layout name is second.xml, set it in the second activity by,setContentView(R.layout.second);, hope it helps, upvote:)

Comment: ya..bro its working perfectly but i can't up vote right now..but it's just a metter of time...I don't know you.but I will find you and vote for you..(taken) ;-)